# Javascript - Undo button to delete added elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I am struggling to make my undo button (delete the last text box created through my 'addText' function, and seemingly cannot get this to work. The Undo button in its current position simply acts like another 'add' button...

HTML:

```
<div id="planner">
  <div class="week week1">
    <div class="add">
      <h1>Weeks</h1>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Add text</button>
      <button type="button"onClick="removeText()">Undo</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week week2">
    <div class="add">
      <h1>Topics</h1>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Add text</button>
      <button type="button"onClick="removeText()">Undo</button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var addButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add button');
var removeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.remove button');

function addText () {
  var self = this;
  var weekParent = self.parentNode.parentNode;
  var textarea = self.parentNode.querySelector('textarea');
  var value = textarea.value;
  var item = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createTextNode(value);

  item.appendChild(text);
  weekParent.appendChild(item);
}

function removeText() {
  var node = document.getElementById('p');
    if (node.hasChildNodes())
      node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
}

for (i = 0; i < addButtons.length; i++) { 
    var self = addButtons[i];
    self.addEventListener("click", addText);
}
```

If div class= "p" is used before the remove button it (in the correct place) can remove Weeks, the textarea and itself(?!) which is absolutely not what I want it to do! In essence, the button cannot remove the newly created text elements. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you think `getElementById()` does? (without reading the documentation, which is what you should have done in the first place).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu no need to snap at the guy like that, I'm not sure it was your intention but you are coming across very rude.

Comment: @AdamH, not my intention, but the question stands and points at the core of the problem: `document.getElementById('p')` selects first element in DOM with `id="p"`.  Hubert, in short, to remove something you need to find it. You can either query DOM (correctly) for it at the time you're performing the action or you can have it stored in a variable for convenient manipulation. Of course, the variable has to be shared in both creation and deletion functions. One such very handy shared scope is the window object.

Comment: Try giving your new element and ID then store that in the global namespace somewhere and then when they hit the undo button find the element by the id to stored and just remove it from the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because you're not selecting the item to be deleted correctly:

```
document.getElementById('p')
```

...selects the first element in DOM with `id="p"`. Which is to say, in your case, it selects nothing.

To select last `<p>` element in current `.week` parent, you could use:

```
.closest('.week').querySelector('p:last-of-type')
```

Here's how I'd personally do it:

```js
function addText(e) {
  // find closest parent with class "week"
  let week = e.target.closest('.week'),
    // if week, find first match for 'textarea' selector
    area = week ? week.querySelector('textarea') : null,
    // if area, get its value
    text = area ? area.value : '';
  if (text.length) {
    // if we got a value, add it as innerText of a new p appended to week
    let item = document.createElement('p');
    item.innerText = text;
    week.appendChild(item);

    // and empty textarea...
    area.value = '';
  } 
}

function removeText(e) {
  // find closest parent of e.target, including self, with class "week"
  let week = e.target.closest('.week'),
    // if week, get it's first match for 'p:last-of-type' selector
    item = week ? week.querySelector('p:last-of-type') : null;
  if (item)
    item.remove()
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
 /* 
  * if any parent of event.target (including itself) 
  * with `add-text` attribute exists...
  */
 if (event.target.closest('[add-text]')) 
   addText(event);

 /*
  * if any parent of event.target (including itself) 
  * with `remove-text` attribute exists...
  */
 if (event.target.closest('[remove-text]')) 
   removeText(event);
})
```

Let's test it:

```js
function addText(e) {
  let week = e.target.closest('.week'),
    area = week ? week.querySelector('textarea') : null,
    text = area ? area.value : '';
  if (text.length) {
    let item = document.createElement('p');
    item.innerText = text;
    week.appendChild(item);
    area.value = '';
  } 
}

function removeText(e) {
  let week = e.target.closest('.week'),
    item = week ? week.querySelector('p:last-of-type') : null;
  if (item)
    item.remove()
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
 if (event.target.closest('[add-text]')) 
   addText(event);
 if (event.target.closest('[remove-text]')) 
   removeText(event);
})
```

```html
<div id="planner">
  <div class="week week1">
    <h1>Weeks</h1>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button type="button" add-text>Add text</button>
    <button type="button" remove-text>Undo</button>
  </div>
  <div class="week week2">
      <h1>Topics</h1>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button type="button" add-text>Add text</button>
      <button type="button" remove-text>Undo</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you know you'll only have this type of elements inside a particular section of your page, move the event listener from `<body>` to that element. i.e.:

```js
document.querySelector('#some-section').addEventListener('click', event => {
  //code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code. Firstly, you should not be using `getElementById("p")`. Instead, use `document.querySelector("p")`. Even then, it would only return the first `<p>` element on the entire page.

What you should probably do is save a reference to the most recently created text element. Something like:

```
var recent;

function addText () {
    var self = this;
    var weekParent = self.parentNode.parentNode;
    var textarea = self.parentNode.querySelector('textarea');
    var value = textarea.value;
    var item = document.createElement("p");
    var text = document.createTextNode(value);

    item.appendChild(text);

    // save the newly created item
    recent = item;

    weekParent.appendChild(item);
}
```

And then when you want to remove it:

```
if(recent != null){
    element.removeChild(recent);
}
```

The second issue I see is that your add button and remove button arrays currently store all `<button>` elements, rather than the ones you're looking for. Give your buttons classes and only query for that specific class. Example:

HTML

```
<button class="add" type="submit">Add text</button>
<button class="remove" type="button"onClick="removeText()">Undo</button>
```

JS

```
var addButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add');
var removeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');
```

Comment: I believe the desired behavior is to remove the last added `<p>` in current `.week`. Which is to say remove last `<p>` element in current `.week`. In what you posted, undo button on week 2 will delete last added element in all document, not in current week. Furthermore, if you took on the task of being helpful, you might mention `<button type="submit">` is not the best choice here.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I was more so looking at the glaring syntax and logic issues that stuck out me. If you want to dig deeper, then be my guest

Answer (score 0):

You should assign all the newly created text elements with an class name so you can select all of them to delete.

```html
<div id="planner">
  <div class="week week1">
    <div class="add">
      <h1>Weeks</h1>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="addTextBtn">Add text</button>
      <button type="button"onClick="removeText()">Undo</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week week2">
    <div class="add">
      <h1>Topics</h1>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="addTextBtn">Add text</button>
      <button type="button"onClick="removeText()">Undo</button>
      </div>
  </div>
<script>
var addButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.addTextBtn');
var removeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.remove button');

function addText () {
  var self = this;
  var weekParent = self.parentNode.parentNode;
  var textarea = self.parentNode.querySelector('textarea');
  var value = textarea.value;
  var item = document.createElement("p");
  item.className = "newText";
  var text = document.createTextNode(value);

  item.appendChild(text);
  weekParent.appendChild(item);
}

function removeText() {
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('newText');
    for(let i = 0; i <nodes.length; i++){
    nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < addButtons.length; i++) { 
    var self = addButtons[i];
    self.addEventListener("click", addText);
}
</script>
```